# space between Currency and Value

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

How to add a space between Currency and Value LIKE CAD 0.00 instead of CAD0.00 in lightning when 'ui:inputCurrency' is used

Answer (score 3):

To override the default currency format make use of  "**`format`**" attribute to change as per your need.

Example:

```
   <ui:inputCurrency aura:id="amount" label="Amount" class="field" value="50" format="CAD #.##"/>
```

Comment: If we use format we have to hard-code the currency value. Want to fetch the currency from user page and display. Is there any other way?

Comment: I cant get you clearly it can also be work by setting dynamic values,can you edit  your question with code what you have tried so far.